# Проблема сериализации в NET6

Tags: c#, .net-6

Не получается сериализовать класс Project через System.Text.Json.Serialization jsonString выдает обратно {}. При этом в Newtonsoft Json все прекрасно работает. Что я делаю не так, как исправить код?

```
public class Project
{
    [JsonProperty("Decks")]
    [JsonPropertyName("Decks")]
    public List<Deck> Decks;

    [JsonProperty("Class")]
    [JsonPropertyName("Class")]
    public string Class;

    [JsonProperty("CWL")]
    [JsonPropertyName("CWL")]
    public double CWL;

    [JsonProperty("LongitudinalSpacing")]
    [JsonPropertyName("LongitudinalSpacing")]
    public int LongitudinalSpacing;

    [JsonProperty("TransverseSpacing")]
    [JsonPropertyName("TransverseSpacing")]
    public int TransverseSpacing;

    [JsonProperty("Particulars")]
    [JsonPropertyName("Particulars")]
    public List<Particular> Particulars;

    [JsonProperty("ProjectNumber")]
    [JsonPropertyName("ProjectNumber")]
    public string ProjectNumber;

    public Project()
    {

    }
   
}

Project projectNS = new Project();
projectNS.CWL = 15000;
projectNS.Class = "FNPP";
projectNS.LongitudinalSpacing = 900;

string netProject = SerializeProject(projectNS);

static string SerializeProject(Project project)
{
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    WriteIndented = true,
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
};

string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize<Project>(project, options);

return jsonString;
}
```

Comment: И самого кода сериализации конечно же не предоставили...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Добавте в `JsonSerializerOptions` такую строку `IncludeFields = true`, т.е. в вашем случае это будет выглядеть так:

```cs
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    WriteIndented = true,
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
    IncludeFields = true
};
```

По умолчанию `System.Text.Json` игнорирует поля и сериализирует только свойста.

Ну или просто поменяйте все поля в ваших классах на свойства, тогда `IncludeFields = true` добавлять не нужно.

Comment: Благодарю! Все сработало, про поля не знал.